# Replace HTTP protocol with Regular Expression in Angular.js

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am using regular expression in java script and just want to replace HTTP:// of images URL having (JPEG, .PNG) extension with a single string.
Like this is a URL

http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg

and want to convert with this

hey/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg

but below URL should not be replace

http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION

I am using this syntax in replace function but it replaces all the URLs

```
var res = str.replace("http:/\//g", "hey");
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a global replacement, you must need to add `g` modifier. `\b` matches a boundary which exists between a word character and a non-word character.

```
str.replace(/\bhttp:\//g, "hey")
```

**Example:**

```
> var s = "http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg"
undefined
> s.replace(/\bhttp:\//g, "hey")
'hey/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg hey/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/24/us/MARION1/MARION1-master675.jpg'
```

Comment: Hey @Avinash here is my target to replace only images URL not others like I have to change only ('jpg, png etc') URL.
Can we do the filter and modify images URL in Regex?

Comment: @abarik try this regex http://regex101.com/r/wW5qU2/1

Comment: Hey @Avinash it's awesome.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey @Avinash it's not working with replace function 
I just did str.replace(\bhttp:\/(?=\S+?\.(?:jpg|png)(?:\s|$))/g,'hey')
it's giving me syntax error,yeah it's stupid question,
I am new in Regex

Comment: you forget to add the delimiters.